Trouble with overloaded operator<< function in circular list
I am working on a program that reads in a polynomial as input, outputs the polynomial, evaluating the polynomial, and adding two polynomials while maintaining a circularly linked list. An analysis using gdb revealed that there is a problem with the Next() member function of CircListIterator class template. What could I be doing wrong with Next()? The code and the output are reproduced below. I apologize for the long code.

main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Polynomial.h"

int main() {
    Polynomial poly1, poly2;
    Polynomial result;

    std::cout << "Enter the first polynomial (format: number_of_terms coef1 expon1 coef2 expon2 ...): ";
    std::cin >> poly1;
    std::cout << "Polynomial 1: " << poly1 << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "Enter the second polynomial (format: number_of_terms coef1 expon1 coef2 expon2 ...): ";
    std::cin >> poly2;
    std::cout << "Polynomial 2: " << poly2 << std::endl;

    float x = 2.0;  // Example value for x
    std::cout << "Value of Polynomial 1 at x = " << x << " is: " << poly1.Evaluate(x) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value of Polynomial 2 at x = " << x << " is: " << poly2.Evaluate(x) << std::endl;
    
    result = poly1 + poly2;
    std::cout << "Sum: " << result << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value of Sum Polynomial at x = " << x << " is: " << result.Evaluate(x) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


Term.h
#ifndef TERM_H
#define TERM_H

struct Term {
    int coef;
    int expon;
    void Init(int c, int e) { coef = c; expon = e; }
};

#endif // TERM_H


ListNode.h
#ifndef LISTNODE_H
#define LISTNODE_H

template <class Type> class CircList;
template <class Type> class CircListIterator;

template <class Type>
class ListNode {
    friend class CircList<Type>;
    friend class CircListIterator<Type>;

    template <class T>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CircList<T>& list);

private:
    Type data;
    ListNode *link;

public:
    ListNode(Type element = 0, ListNode *next = nullptr) : data(element), link(next) {}
};

#endif // LISTNODE_H


CircList.h
#ifndef CIRCLIST_H
#define CIRCLIST_H

#include <iostream>
#include "ListNode.h"

template <class Type> class CircListIterator;

template <class Type>
class CircList {
    friend class CircListIterator<Type>;

private:
    ListNode<Type> *last;

public:
    static ListNode<Type>* av;
    CircList() : last(nullptr) {}
    ~CircList();

    void RetNode(ListNode<Type>* x);
    ListNode<Type> *GetNode();
    ListNode<Type> *getFirst() const;
    ListNode<Type> *getLast() const;
    ListNode<Type> *Insert(ListNode<Type> *x, Type i);
    void Delete(ListNode<Type> *x);
    void Attach(const Type &item);
};

template <class Type>
ListNode<Type>* CircList<Type>::av = nullptr;

template <class Type>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CircList<Type>& list);

// Include the implementation here
#include "CircList.cpp"

#endif // CIRCLIST_H



CircList.cpp
#ifndef CIRCLIST_CPP
#define CIRCLIST_CPP

#include "CircList.h"

template <class Type>
ListNode<Type>* CircList<Type>::GetNode() {
    ListNode<Type>* x;
    if (!av) x = new ListNode<Type>;
    else { x = av; av = av->link; }
    return x;
}

template <class Type>
void CircList<Type>::RetNode(ListNode<Type>* x) {
    x->link = av;
    av = x;
}

template <class Type>
CircList<Type>::~CircList() {
    if (last != nullptr) {
        ListNode<Type>* current = last->link;
        while (current != last) {
            ListNode<Type>* temp = current;
            current = current->link;
            delete temp;
        }
        delete last;
    }
}

template <class Type>
ListNode<Type> *CircList<Type>::getFirst() const {
    if (last == nullptr) return nullptr;
    else return last->link;
}

template <class Type>
ListNode<Type> *CircList<Type>::getLast() const {
    return last;
}

template <class Type>
ListNode<Type> *CircList<Type>::Insert(ListNode<Type> *x, Type i) {
    if (last == nullptr) {
        last = new ListNode<Type>(i);
        last->link = last;
        return last;
    }
    ListNode<Type> *temp = new ListNode<Type>(i, x->link);
    x->link = temp;
    if (x == last) {
        last = temp;
    }
    return temp;
}

template <class Type>
void CircList<Type>::Delete(ListNode<Type> *x) {
    if (last == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "The list is empty" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    if (last->link == last && last == x) {
        delete last;
        last = nullptr;
        return;
    }
    ListNode<Type> *temp = last->link;
    ListNode<Type> *prev = last;
    do {
        if (temp == x) {
            prev->link = temp->link;
            if (x == last) {
                last = prev;
            }
            if (x == last->link) {
                last->link = x->link;
            }
            delete x;
            return;
        }
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->link;
    } while (temp != last->link);

    std::cout << "Node not found" << std::endl;
}

template <class Type>
void CircList<Type>::Attach(const Type &item) {
    ListNode<Type>* newNode = new ListNode<Type>(item);
    if (last == nullptr) {
        last = newNode;
        last->link = last;
    } else {
        newNode->link = last->link;
        last->link = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    }
    std::cout << "Term with Exponent " << item.expon 
              << " and coefficient " << item.coef << " added. " << std::endl;
}

#endif // CIRCLIST_CPP



CircListIterator.h
#ifndef CIRCLISTITERATOR_H
#define CIRCLISTITERATOR_H

#include "CircList.h"

template <class Type>
class CircListIterator {
public:
    CircListIterator(const CircList<Type> &l);
    Type getData();
    bool NotNull() const;
    bool NextNotNull() const;
    Type* First();
    Type* Next();
    bool IsEmpty() const;
    ListNode<Type>* CurrentPosition() const;

private:
    const CircList<Type> &list;
    ListNode<Type> *current;
};

// Include the implementation here
#include "CircListIterator.cpp"

#endif // CIRCLISTITERATOR_H


CircListIterator.cpp
#ifndef CIRCLISTITERATOR_CPP
#define CIRCLISTITERATOR_CPP

#include "CircListIterator.h"

template <class Type>
CircListIterator<Type>::CircListIterator(const CircList<Type> &l)
    : list(l), current(l.getFirst()) {}

template <class Type>
Type CircListIterator<Type>::getData() {
    return current->data;
}

template <class Type>
bool CircListIterator<Type>::NotNull() const {
    return current != nullptr ? true : false;
}

template <class Type>
bool CircListIterator<Type>::NextNotNull() const {
    return current != nullptr && current->link != nullptr ? true : false;
}

template <class Type>
Type* CircListIterator<Type>::First() {
    current = list.getFirst();
    if (current && current->data.expon == -1) {
        current = current->link;
        if (current == list.getFirst()) {
            current = nullptr;
        }
    }
    return current ? &current->data : nullptr;
}

template <class Type>
Type* CircListIterator<Type>::Next() {
    if (current) {
        current = current->link;
        if (current && (current->data.expon == -1 || current == list.getFirst())) {
            current = nullptr;
        }
        return current ? &current->data : nullptr;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template <class Type>
bool CircListIterator<Type>::IsEmpty() const {
    const ListNode<Type>* first = list.getFirst();
    return first == nullptr || (first->data.expon == -1 && first->link == first);
}

template <class Type>
ListNode<Type>* CircListIterator<Type>::CurrentPosition() const {
    return current;
}

#endif // CIRCLISTITERATOR_CPP


Polynomial.h
#ifndef POLYNOMIAL_H
#define POLYNOMIAL_H

#include "CircList.h"
#include "Term.h"
#include "CircListIterator.h"

class Polynomial {
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Polynomial&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Polynomial&);
    friend Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial&, const Polynomial&);

private:
    CircList<Term> poly;

public:
    Polynomial() : poly() {}
    Polynomial(const Polynomial& other);
    const Polynomial& operator=(const Polynomial& a);
    ~Polynomial();
    float Evaluate(float x);
};

#endif // POLYNOMIAL_H


Polynomial.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "Polynomial.h"

Polynomial::Polynomial(const Polynomial& other) : poly() {
    CircListIterator<Term> iter(other.poly);
    const Term* t = iter.First();
    while (t != nullptr) {
        poly.Attach(*t);
        t = iter.Next();
    }
}

const Polynomial& Polynomial::operator=(const Polynomial& a) {
    if (this != &a) {  // Check for self-assignment
        // Clean up existing polynomial
        CircListIterator<Term> iter(poly);
        Term* t = iter.First();
        while (t != nullptr) {
            poly.Delete(iter.CurrentPosition());
            t = iter.Next();
        }

        // Copy the polynomial 'a'
        CircListIterator<Term> aIter(a.poly);
        const Term* aTerm = aIter.First();
        while (aTerm != nullptr) {
            poly.Attach(*aTerm);
            aTerm = aIter.Next();
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

Polynomial::~Polynomial() {
    CircListIterator<Term> iter(poly);
    Term* t = iter.First();
    while (t != nullptr) {
        poly.Delete(iter.CurrentPosition());
        t = iter.Next();
    }
}

Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial& a, const Polynomial& b) {
    CircListIterator<Term> Aiter(a.poly);
    CircListIterator<Term> Biter(b.poly);
    Polynomial c;
    Term *p = Aiter.First();
    Term *q = Biter.First();
    Term temp;

    while (p != nullptr || q != nullptr) {
        if (p == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "Attaching q: coef=" << q->coef << ", expon=" << q->expon << std::endl;
            temp.Init(q->coef, q->expon);
            c.poly.Attach(temp);
            q = Biter.Next();
        } else if (q == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "Attaching p: coef=" << p->coef << ", expon=" << p->expon << std::endl;
            temp.Init(p->coef, p->expon);
            c.poly.Attach(temp);
            p = Aiter.Next();
        } else if (p->expon == q->expon) {
            std::cout << "Summing: p->coef=" << p->coef << ", q->coef=" << q->coef << std::endl;
            int sum = p->coef + q->coef;
            if (sum != 0) {
                temp.Init(sum, p->expon);
                c.poly.Attach(temp);
            }
            p = Aiter.Next();
            q = Biter.Next();
        } else if (p->expon > q->expon) {
            std::cout << "Attaching p: coef=" << p->coef << ", expon=" << p->expon << std::endl;
            temp.Init(p->coef, p->expon);
            c.poly.Attach(temp);
            p = Aiter.Next();
        } else {
            std::cout << "Attaching q: coef=" << q->coef << ", expon=" << q->expon << std::endl;
            temp.Init(q->coef, q->expon);
            c.poly.Attach(temp);
            q = Biter.Next();
        }
    }

    return c;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Polynomial& x) {
    int n, coef, expon;
    Term temp;
    
    x.poly = CircList<Term>();  // Clear existing polynomial

    temp.Init(0, -1);  // Create head node with exponent -1
    x.poly.Attach(temp);

    is >> n;  // Read number of terms

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        is >> coef >> expon;
        if (coef != 0) {  // Ignore terms with zero coefficients
            temp.Init(coef, expon);
            x.poly.Attach(temp);
        }
    }
    return is;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Polynomial& p) {
    CircListIterator<Term> iter(p.poly);
    const Term* t = iter.First();
    
    if (t == nullptr) {
        os << "0";
        return os;
    }

    bool firstTerm = true;
    while (t != nullptr) {
        if (t->expon != -1) {
            if (!firstTerm) {
                os << (t->coef > 0 ? " + " : " - ");
            } else {
                if (t->coef < 0) {
                    os << "-";
                }
                firstTerm = false;
            }

            int absCoef = std::abs(t->coef);
            if (absCoef != 1 || t->expon == 0) {
                os << absCoef;
            }

            if (t->expon != 0) {
                os << "x";
                if (t->expon != 1) {
                    os << "^" << t->expon;
                }
            }
        }
        t = iter.Next();
    }

    return os;
}

float Polynomial::Evaluate(float x) {
    float result = 0.0;
    CircListIterator<Term> iter(poly);
    const Term* t = iter.First();
    
    while (t != nullptr) {
        result += t->coef * std::pow(x, t->expon);
        t = iter.Next();
    }
    
    return result;
}


Output:
Enter the first polynomial (format: number_of_terms coef1 expon1 coef2 expon2 ...): Term with Exponent -1 and coefficient 0 added. 
3 1 2 2 1 1 0
Term with Exponent 2 and coefficient 1 added. 
Term with Exponent 1 and coefficient 2 added. 
Term with Exponent 0 and coefficient 1 added. 
Polynomial 1: x^2 + 2x + 1
Enter the second polynomial (format: number_of_terms coef1 expon1 coef2 expon2 ...): Term with Exponent -1 and coefficient 0 added. 
3 1 2 3 1 2 0
Term with Exponent 2 and coefficient 1 added. 
Term with Exponent 1 and coefficient 3 added. 
Term with Exponent 0 and coefficient 2 added. 
Polynomial 2: x^2 + 3x + 2
Value of Polynomial 1 at x = 2 is: 9
Value of Polynomial 2 at x = 2 is: 12
Summing: p->coef=1, q->coef=1
Term with Exponent 2 and coefficient 2 added. 
Summing: p->coef=2, q->coef=3
Term with Exponent 1 and coefficient 5 added. 
Summing: p->coef=1, q->coef=2
Term with Exponent 0 and coefficient 3 added. 
Term with Exponent 2 and coefficient 2 added. 
Term with Exponent 1 and coefficient 5 added. 
Term with Exponent 0 and coefficient 3 added.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555657b in CircListIterator<Term>::Next (this=0x7fffffffeb10) at /home/CircListIterator.cpp:42


What exactly does this mean "An analysis using gdb revealed that there is a problem with the Next()" ?

do you mean that the code crashes in Next ? That doesnt mean that the problem is in Next

Thanks for the comment. I meant that the function call to Next() resulted in a segmentation fault. I had been thinking maybe there is a problem with getFirst().

you shouldnt call the files with the template definitions ".cpp". Its somewhat confusing, because you usually never include a cpp file.

Any reason you are writing your own list class instead of using std::list?

#include "CircListIterator.cpp" - no, move the implementation of the class template into the header file

This question really needs a [mre].

It's in Polynomial::~Polynomial() - you call iter.Next() but current is deleted so current->link dereferences an invalidated pointer.

when writing any non trivial (aka something more than HelloWorld) program you must test its part in isolation. You dont want to face a bug without knowing if the bug is in the linkedlist or in the polynomial or in the code using the two. And you do not need to, because you can test them separately. This is part of the reason we ask you to provide a [mcve]

Thank you so much everyone for your contribution. I solved the issue by rewriting the destructor. I will also move the implementation into the header file. Thanks again!

@benhpark Great! You'll also need to rewrite Polynomial::operator=(const Polynomial& a) for the same reason.

if (!av) -- the 1st node in a circular list must be self-referencing (e.g. av == av->next == last == last->next). Meaning when you add the 1st node, it is both av and last until the next node is added. This applies to deleting nodes when 2 nodes remain. When you delete one of the last two, the survivor becomes self-referencing as well. You need a check av == last in both cases.

Much appreciated. I will add the check (av==last) as well.
